# Python: Extract the Date and Time using Regex

Tags: python

Problem Statement:

I need to collect the logs from a file only after a particular time which can be in the following format 'Aug 7 11:00:00.000' or 'Aug 7 11:00:00'. These logs are in a different txt file and are of the format:

```
Aug  7 11:00:00 abc newsyslog[25714]: logfile turned over due to size>1024K
Aug  7 11:00:00.000  abc xyz lol
```

and so on.

How do I extract this particular date and time using regex and then collect the logs only after a specified time ? Is there any other better way to use other than regex.

Right now using this:

```
import re

monthnames = "(?:Jan\w*|Feb\w*|Mar\w*|Apr\w*|May|Jun\w?|Jul\w?|Aug\w*|Sep\w*|Oct\w*|Nov(?:ember)?|Dec\w*)"

pattern1 = re.compile(r"(\d{1,4}[\/\\\-]+\d{1,2}[\/\\\-]+\d{2,4})")

pattern4 = re.compile(r"(?:[\d,. \-]*[,. \-])?%s(?:[\,\.\ \-]+[\d]+[stndrh]*)+[:\d]*[\ ]?(PM)?(AM)?([\ \-\+\d]{4,7}|[UTCESTGMT\ ]{2,4})*"%monthnames, re.I)

patterns = [pattern4, pattern1]

s='Aug 7 11:00:00.000'

for pattern in patterns:
    print re.findall(pattern,s)
```

But it returns nothing, an empty list !

Need help !

P.S - I can use only traditional libraries in python, because this is an automation script for Junos

Comment: Why not use the `strptime` function of the built-in `datetime` module?

Comment: Can you please give an example ?

Comment: `datetime.strptime('Mon, August 13, 2018', '%a, %B %d, %Y')` returns the `datetime` object corresponding to August 13, 2018. You can learn more by reading the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely don't need regex for this - simple split on a whitespace and collecting the first two results should be more than enough, i.e.:

```
log_lines = ["Aug  7 11:00:00 abc newsyslog[25714]: logfile turned over due to size>1024K",
             "Aug  7 11:00:00.000  abc xyz lol"]  # we'll use a list as an example

for line in log_lines:
    date_string = " ".join(line.split(None, 3)[:-1])
    print(date_string)

# Aug 7 11:00:00
# Aug 7 11:00:00.000
```

Now, you can use [`datetime.datetime.strptime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) to parse it into a native date-time object, but you might be limited with the formatting (i.e. `%b` is a month abbreviation only for the current locale and not all platforms/versions support single digit dates) so, given such a simple structure you might want to rebuild your captured date-time strings before getting them to parse to maximize compatibility:

```
month_abbr = {"jan": 1, "feb": 2, "mar": 3, "apr": 4, "may": 5, "jun": 6,
              "jul": 7, "aug": 8, "sep": 9, "oct": 10, "nov": 11, "dec": 12}

def parse_date(log_line):
    mon, day, tim = line.split(None, 3)[:-1]
    date_string = "{:02} {:02} ".format(month_abbr[mon.lower()], int(day)) + tim
    try:
        return datetime.datetime.strptime(date_string, "%m %d %H:%M:%S.%f")
    except ValueError as e:
        return datetime.datetime.strptime(date_string, "%m %d %H:%M:%S")

log_lines = ["Aug  7 11:00:00 abc newsyslog[25714]: logfile turned over due to size>1024K",
             "Aug  7 11:00:00.000  abc xyz lol"]  # we'll use a list as an example

for line in log_lines:
    date_object = parse_date(line)
    print(date_object)

# 1900-08-07 11:00:00
# 1900-08-07 11:00:00
```

NOTE: your date-time objects will have `1900` as their year because your logs do not have the year information. The second date-time object contains its microseconds data as well, it just doesn't print out with the default representation of an [`datetime.datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects) object.

You can now compare those date-time objects to other date-time objects and filter out/print/whatever you want to do those lines that match your criteria, e.g. if you want only logs created **after** `Aug 7`:

```
log_lines = ["Aug  7 11:00:00 abc newsyslog[25714]: logfile turned over due to size>1024K",
             "Aug  7 11:00:00.000  abc xyz lol",
             "Aug  8 11:00:00 foo bar"]  # we'll use a list as an example

min_date = datetime.datetime(1900, 8, 8)  # minimum date set to Aug 8

for line in log_lines:
    if parse_date(line) >= min_date:
        print(line)

# Aug  8 11:00:00 foo bar
```

Comment: Once I extract the time, I need to extract only those logs that were collected after the specified time like once I extract Aug 6 12:45:30.650, suppose the date and time are parsed as Aug 6 13:45: 50.123. I need to extract logs only after this specified time. How do I do that ? Stuck for a long time now !

Comment: I need to collect the logs using both date and time as parameter, this is only comparing the date

Comment: @P.Saini - `datetime.datetime` contains a time component, too. For example, if you want to set the minimum date to 8th of August at 8:30am you can use: `min_date = datetime.datetime(1900, 8, 8, 8, 30)`. Check the [`datetime.datetime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime) signature to see all of the available components when defining it.

Answer (score 1):

I think regex is an overkill for that, I would've extracted the date part, something like:

```
' '.join(line.split()[0:3])
```

And use [strptime()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html?highlight=strptime#datetime.datetime.strptime) with the longer format, catch the exception, and try with strptime for the shorter format:

```
from datetime import datetime

def get_date(date_str):
    try:
        return datetime.strptime(date_str, '%b %d %H:%M:%S.%f')
    except ValueError:
        return datetime.strptime(date_str, '%b %d %H:%M:%S')
```